# Convert a text to binary in c# taking Enter key as an input

Tags: c#, string, binary

I am quite new to c# and I am trying to make a C# program to convert String inputs to Binary Sequence, even special characters ( for example *"SpaceBar key"* returns 00100000). The code is working just fine but the problem i have is that i want to take "Enter Key" as an input. Because whenever i press ***Enter***, it just runs the code.

Here is my code,

```
using System;

namespace StringToBinary
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter text you wish to convert:");
       string a = Console.ReadLine();
        foreach (char c in a)
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly is the behavior you want to achieve? You need some kind of key that tells the code to run, otherwise you will have an endless input doing nothing. Or you do something like a live-translation, but then something like deleting a typo or seeing what you have typed as string is challenging. An alternative would be reading a file instead of text from the console, or a GUI application.

Answer (score 0):

Begin with this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter text you wish to convert (ctrl-c to brek):");

while (true)
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {cki.Key}, Char: {cki.KeyChar}, (hex: {((ushort)cki.KeyChar).ToString("X4")}, binary: {Convert.ToString((ushort)cki.KeyChar, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')}), Modifiers: {cki.Modifiers}");
}
```

Run it a little (trying various key combos) and then decide what you want to handle exactly.

Comment: Thanks helped me a lot.